# R: Modifying a data.table via a chained subset with assignment by reference not working

Tags: r, reference, data.table

I got a data.table from which I need to take different subsets, and from each of them I need to sample rows and assign a value to the sampled rows. This assigned value should appear in the original data.table too (modification by reference).

I tried the following which gives no error, but does not work:

```
require(data.table)
dt <- data.table(a=c(1,2,3,1,2,3), s=logical())
print(dt[a==2][sample(.N,1)][, s := TRUE]) # No value is assigned to s.
print(dt) # Here the assigned logical values should be present too.
```

Edit:
The solution suggested in the first comment by akrun is close, but used in a for loop is does not deliver the desired result and changes the logical column in dt only twice instead of three times.

```
for (i in unique(dt$a)) {
  dt[dt[a==i, .I[sample(.N, 1)]], s := TRUE]
}
```

Why is that?

Comment: You may need `dt[dt[a==2, .I[sample(.N, 1)]], s := TRUE]`

Comment: I can't reproduce the lack of assignment to `s`. What I can reproduce is a known `data.table` "feature" (bug) that assignment operations don't print immediately. If you follow your print with `[]`, as in `print(.)[]`, then it *does* print the row, with `s` assigned as `TRUE`. As far as assigning that back into the original frame, then ... you are completely off here: a subset operation does not trace back into the original frame. You'll need to sample the row externally and bring it back into `dt`.

Comment: Nope, that command *does* modify `s` in the resulting frame, but not in the original.

Comment: Thanks for the info. akrun delivered the solution!

Comment: I think you are right.  It matters only when grouped `.I is an integer vector equal to seq_len(nrow(x)). While grouping, it holds for each item in the group, its row location in x.`.  Probably you may need to create a sequence column before that i.e. `dt[, rn = .I]` and then use the `rn` i.e. `for(i in un1) {print(dt[a == i,  rn[sample(.N, 1)]])}`

Comment: Thanks, I tried that but I think I misunderstood your comment. I did not fully understand where and how to utilize the new acquired row ids.

Comment: In the end, how many times are you sampling, and are you doing it across all values of `a`?

Comment: It seems like the edit suggests a grouping version of what @akrun did `dt[dt[, .I[sample(.N, 1)], a]$V1, s := TRUE]`

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be the solution! It works fine even without the need to have a loop. I do not completely understand how it works. You take a subset based on the row numbers and every unique value in column "a" with sample size 1 and assign the logical values to this subset. I do not get where the temporary column "V1" is coming from and what it contains. Are the row numbers contained in it?

Comment: There are a few things. The loop version doesn’t work because `.I` is not global. That is, after you subset, `.I` is only `1:2` based on your example data. That is it does not work, your loop only produces 1 or 2 each pass. You can probably google more about .I, but yes, V1 is the name assigned to the values of the `.I[sample(...)]` part. You could also just run that part of the code to see what’s happening. One last thing, I think you could also do `sample(.I, 1)` for similar results